# Merge 5 arrays of strings in one

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How to merge multiple (5 arrays in one):

```
var arr1 = ['a','b'];
var arr2 = ['c','d','n'];
var arr3 = ['e','f'];
var arr4 = ['g','h'];
var arr5 = ['o','p','q'];
```

I try with this but no luck:

```
objCls = arr1 + arr2 + arr3 + arr4 + arr5;
var objectsClass = objCls.split(',');
```

Comment: Define "merge". Just a simple union? Or do you want to filter out duplicates?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var all = [].concat(arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4, arr5)
```

All five of the input arrays are left untouched. Documentation: [`Array::concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

Comment: May be if i add another empty and do concat of arr1 with rest of arrays...?

Comment: @Art-of-Life: I'm not sure if I understood your comment correctly, but I've updated the snippet to make it clear that `arr1` is not mutated. It definitely reads better this way.

Comment: Man thank you ... I`m shoore that is working, but for me it`s not... What is wrong..? http://jsfiddle.net/ArtofLife_again/JkhHH/8/

Comment: `objCls.join(',');` instead of `objCls.split(',');` just look at the Javascript Erros.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ArtofLife_again/JkhHH/17/ I got it... @davidchambers: This is the best solution. Thank`s

Comment: We don't need to create this empty array just to get the concat method.

Comment: Correct, but the code's behaviour is clearer this way. `arr1.concat(arr2, arr3, arr4, arr5)` suggests that perhaps `arr1` is mutated. This way, there's no room for confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Try concat:

```
var c = arr1.concat(arr2, arr3, arr4, arr5);
```

Answer (score 1):

arr1.concat(arr2).concat(arr3) and so forth?
or even better arr1.concat(arr2, arr3,arr4).
I see It has already been proposed :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Array.prototype.merge = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
        var array = arguments[i];
        for(var j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
            if(this.indexOf(array[j]) === -1) { //remove this if condition if you dont want unique values in your array
                this.push(array[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return this;
};
```

Comment: Why create `Array::merge`? Doesn't `Array::concat` do exactly what we want?

Comment: @Sudhir - Note that your solution is not really an "alternative", because it does something different. `Array.prototype.concat` will happily result in an array with duplicate values, whereas your method will not.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the concat() method http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp
This is exactly what you're looking for :)

Comment: Please link to Mozilla's documentation. It's better. :)